# Understanding the proof of the composite function theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I'm having some trouble understanding the justification for one step in the proof of the composite function theorem. The following is the proof from Wendell Flemings functions of several variables.

The referenced proposition, i.e proposition 4.4 states:

> Let ${\bf{g}}$ be differentiable at $\bf{t_{0}}$, then given $\varepsilon >0$, there exists a neighbourhood $\Omega_{0}$ such that:
> $$|{\bf{g(t)}}-{\bf{g(t_{0})}}|\leq(||D{\bf{g(t_{0})}}||+\varepsilon)|\bf{t-t_{0}}|$$
> for every ${\bf{t}} \in \Omega_{0}$

Here is the proof:
[image]

I understand the proof up until the choice of $\delta$, where I would have chosen $\delta = \min \{\delta_{0},\eta\}$ instead of the suggested $\delta = \min \{\delta_{0},C^{-1} \eta \}$.

What is the justification for choosing $C^{-1} \eta$ as opposed to simply $\eta$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line, when rewritten slightly, is: $$|F(t_0 + k) - F(t_0)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{C}|x - x_0| = \frac{\varepsilon}{C}|g(t_0+k) - g(t_0)| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{C}C|k| = \varepsilon |k|$$
But the important part is that the condition for the above to hold is on $|k|$, as in the $\delta$ is to be compared to $|k|$: assuming $|k| < \delta_0$, and for the choice of $x$ and $x_0$ done, we know $|x - x_0| \leq C|k|$ holds, and as such we want $|x - x_0| \leq C|k| < \eta$ to complete the puzzle and have the leftmost inequality, meaning: $|k| < C^{-1}\eta$.